# filter by id in mongo db in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, axios

How do I filter by id in mongodb using a http post request with axios. I tried using this code for the data but I get no results. I tried searching online but I couldn't find anything.

var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

```
var o_id = new ObjectId(id);

var data = JSON.stringify({
    "collection": "collection",
    "database": "database",
    "dataSource": "dataSource",
    "filter":{
        "_id": o_id
        }
    });
```

I think the issue is ObjectId(id) is enclosed in a string which I think it isn't suppose to be but I tried removing the string enclosure of it and it gave me a parameter error.

Comment: `db.collection.find({
  _id: ObjectId("your-id-here")
})`?

Comment: i don't know how to get a reference to the db variable, i am making a http request. I figured out how to get it to work.  I have to use this filter "filter": { "_id": { "$oid": id } }

Comment: if you're making a request to some other service that you don't run, you *can't* use anything on the mongodb because you aren't the server (that's a good thing). Don't send a base64 `ObjectId` inside json, it won't work, needs to be string. If it is a server you are developing, ou will have to add the functionality.